# How to set TV Volume to 50%?

Tags: cec-client

I would like to set the TV volume to 50% how do I achieve this with the cec-client command or other.  I am aware of the [volup] [voldown] but that must be a dumb API comparable to walking blind-folded.

Thanks for providing your insights and hopefully a solution.

I tried the following command but the post never explained what it meant nor can I intrepet the output :(

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo "tx 20:71" | cec-client RPI -s -d 4
opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
NOTICE:  [               3]     connection opened
NOTICE:  [             268]     registering new CEC client - v4.0.4
NOTICE:  [             960]     CEC client registered: libCEC version = 4.0.4, client version = 4.0.4, firmware version = 1, logical address(es) = Recorder 1 (1) , physical address: 4.0.0.0, compiled on Linux-4.15.0-48-generic ... , features: P8_USB, DRM, P8_detect, randr, RPi, Exynos, AOCEC
NOTICE:  [            3535]     unregistering client: libCEC version = 4.0.4, client version = 4.0.4, firmware version = 1, logical address(es) = Recorder 1 (1) , physical address: 4.0.0.0, compiled on Linux-4.15.0-48-generic ... , features: P8_USB, DRM, P8_detect, randr, RPi, Exynos, AOCEC
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cec-client -h
```

Once I figure out this my next step would be how to issue these commands from a TypeScript(JS) web app running inside the Chromium browser on the Pi4 of course.

Comment: After reading [this](https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec/blob/master/src/cec-client/cec-client.cpp#L350) you can probably use : `echo volup | cec-client -s -d 1` or `echo voldown | cec-client -s -d 1` X times neccessary starting with known sound level value. For web application you can make `AJAX` request to web server running `PHP` (python, perl or another langage) and use system() (or other related function) or `CGI` for running your cec-client command.

Comment: Are you confirming there is no command for a direct value?
If I issue the volup command the TV stays **ALWAYS** at "7" out of 100, the command spits out 7F repeatedly, is that a hex value or am I expected to interpret it as 7 and discard the "F" ?  I am able to turn off/on the TV with "tx 20:04" and "tx 20:36"

Comment: `Are you confirming there is no command for a direct value` no sorry I don't know for that. `7F` seem's to be hex. If cec-client still does not respond to the remote control, type "`as`" directly in the output of cec-client to switch the television to active source.

Comment: Have you tried to sniff the volume buttons on the remote control with the cec client? Maybe some useful information can be displayed. (using `-d 1` not `-d 4`)

Comment: Also, from [here](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=211527) : `unfortunately almost no TVs support volume control via CEC` , you can also read [here](http://libcec.pulse-eight.com/vendor/support)

Comment: Can you explain what command lines are used to "sniff" the remote control. By this you mean pickup the signals from the remote volume/up down.  Then some how you can have cec-client transmit them? Thanks.

Comment: With `cec-client` but if cec-client still does not respond to the remote control, type `as` directly in the output of cec-client to switch the television to active source. But if `volup` command not work , it's a bad  starting point.